# ImageMagick webp:target-size= does not work

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When I'm running this command

```
magick in.jpg -resize 1768 -define webp:target-size=235000 out.webp
```

webp:target-size= has no effect.

On the other hand when I convert to webp with -quality is properly working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-13 Q16 x64 2021-05-17 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 192829914
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenCL OpenMP(2.0)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zip zlib
```

**UPDATE**:

I just upgraded to
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-36 Q16-HDRI x64 be0bdc3:20220530

which includes
libwebp 1.2.2 [020F]

and still
webp:target-size= has no effect.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 7.0.11-13 is rather old. Perhaps that feature was fixed in a later version. Try upgrading. Current version is 7.1.0-35

Comment: convert -list format gives: WEBP* WEBP      rw+   WebP Image Format (libwebp 1.0.3 [020E]) -- this version of libwebp supports the -size (webp:target-size=value). But I'm going to upgrade ImageMagick anyway just to be sure. Please, do you know if with the upgrade is also included the upgraded libwebp, or do I have to upgrade libwebp separately? I'n on Windows10.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. I am not on Windows.

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php for the defines that can be used with Imagemagick for webp

Comment: I would be sure to use the latest Webp (1.2.2). Perhaps that feature you want was implemented in later versions than 1.0.3